# Logistic regression prediction out of boundaries in SAS

Tags: logistic, sas

I have a big issue with my logistic regression in SAS.

[image]

```
ods noproctitle;
ods graphics / imagemap=on;

proc logistic data=WORK.SEMEN;
    class Accident / param=glm;
    model Diagnosis(event='1')=Accident / link=logit stb corrb rsquare 
        technique=fisher;
run;
```

Here you can see the summary statistics:

[image]

As you may have already noticed, the intercept is too big to keep the prediction between 0 and 1

Comment: The prediction from a logistic regression mathematically cannot be less than zero or bigger than one, no matter what your intercept is.  What leads you to believe this is so?

Comment: All coefficients act on log odds, not on probabilities. That is the magic of logistic regression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link function is logit, aka log(odds). So, to find the probability:

$$\log(\text{odds}(\text{diag} = 1)) = -2.6149 + 0.9620 (\text{noAccident})$$

The odds(diag=1) when there is an accident is then just -2.9149. To get the predicted probability:

$$\log(\text{odds}(\text{diag} = 1)) = -2.6149$$

$$\text{odds}(\text{diag} = 1) = \exp^{-2.6149}$$

$$\text{P}(\text{diag} = 1) = \frac{\exp^{-2.6149}}{\exp^{-2.6149} + 1}$$

And you can do the same for the situation when there is no accident. You'll see that both are within 0 and 1. Apologize that it's not the most beautiful notation but I hope you got the idea.